# Mostrar 2 decimales o numero exacto en columna DataGridView

Tags: c#, datatables, ms-access

Tengo la siguiente tabla de access la cual necesito llamar y mostrar en un WinForm:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestion es que al mostrarla en el DGV, los datos no son exactos (me corta mas decimales, si un numero es 96,40 me lo representa como 96,39999....) y queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo de llamada de tabla de access**

```
string connString ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\\Mis sistemas\\sikor2000_bs.mdb";

      using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
      {
         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT cod_parte, cliente, descripcion, unidad, precio, disponible, es_rollo FROM partes", conn);

         conn.Open();

         OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

         adapter.Fill(results);

         dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
       }
```

Como puedo hacer para que el DGV me muestre los datos como estan si o si sin que el mismo los formatee de esa forma? (puesto que ocupo pasar esta tabla a una bd de sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar este formato

`dataGridView1.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3"`

También te dejo la documentación oficial

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Me muestra esto 
`Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' en mscorlib.dll. Información adicional: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.`

Comment: me funciono de la siguiente manera, casi igual `dataGridView1.Columns["precio"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3";`

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que hagas uso del evento **`CellFormatting`**.

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("precio"))
{
    //Asegúrese de que el valor sea una cadena.
    String stringValue = e.Value as string;

    if (stringValue == null) return;

    e.Value = String.Format("{0:0.##}", e.Value);
}
```

Comment: Por qué? Recuerda debes argumentar

Comment: soy yo o es VB?